# Multiply Negative Numbers Without Asterisk

Tags: javascript

I am currently doing a function that multiplies numbers without any arithmetic operator esp the asterisk operator.

Here's my function so far:

```
function product(num1, num2) {
  var prod = 0;

  for(var i=1; i<=num2; i++){
    prod += num1;
   }
   return prod;
}

var output = product(4, 7);
console.log(output); // --> 28
```

This actually works except for negative numbers. How can make sure that when I passed a negative number it can still multiply it correctly? Am I doing this right or is there a better way to do it?

THnaks!
Newbie here.

Comment: if num2 < 0 negate both num1 and num2

Comment: "multiplies numbers without any arithmetic operator" - but you are using the `+=` operator. That is an arithmetic operator!

Comment: `i++` is an arithmetic operator too. It is the same as `i = i + 1` in this context. What operators are you actually allowed to use for this exercise?

Comment: Go back to basics. Multiplication works by multiplying the numbers ignoring the sign. Then at the end apply the rule of `++ = +`, `-- = +` and `+- = -`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @Jaromanda X 's reminding,

I shouldn't use * operator.

When num2<0 your code goes wrong,

Try this

```
function product(num1, num2) {
  var prod = 0;
  if(num2<=0){
    num2=-num2;
    num1=-num1;
  }

  for(var i=1; i<=num2; i++){
    prod += num1;
   }
   return prod;
}
```

Comment: but ... you're using `*` ... why not `num1= -num1; num2 = -num2;`

Comment: `num*=-1`  is same as `num=num*-1`

Comment: I fully understand what `*= -1` does!!! Read the question - the OP is trying to do this without using `*` operator :p

Comment: The question actually says "without _any_ arithmetic operator" (emphasis added). That would rule out the unary `-`, `++`, and `+=` operators too.

Comment: and `+` - so, yeah, there's that

Answer (score 0):

You can use some mild recursion to negate `num2` and the result if `num2` is negative. That way, the rest of your function can remain unchanged:

```js
function product(num1, num2) {
  if (num2 < 0) { return -product(num1, -num2); }

  var prod = 0;

  for(var i=1; i<=num2; i++){
    prod += num1;
   }
   
   return prod;
}

console.log(product(4, 7));
console.log(product(-4, 7));
console.log(product(4, -7));
console.log(product(-4, -7));
```